# Calculating Manhattan Distance

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm implementing NxN puzzels in Java 2D array int[][] state. am required to use the Manhattan heuristic in the following way:

```
             the sum of the vertical and horizontal distances from 
                the current node to the goal node/tile

                                +(plus)

    the number of moves to reach the goal node from the initial position
```

At the moment I don't know how to go further. Am a beginner in puzzle game programming with 2D arrays so am having trouble to understand certain concepts. How can I write this code in Java?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is more a math question, but anyways the Manhattan distance is the sum of the absolute values of the horizontal and the vertical distance

```
int distance = Math.abs(x1-x0) + Math.abs(y1-y0);
```

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is that all i need to calculate the horizontal and vertical distances? Am a beginner so need help. I thought maybe i have to move from tile to tile and add 1 each time to the accumulated cost.

Comment: The code I gave is just for the plain Manhattan distance - if I understand the puzzle correctly you have to add the number of moves to that.

Comment: Eddy: yes, because the mahattan distance is the same, regardless which "street" do you take to get there.

Comment: For some reason, when I did my AI class, I was under the impression that Manhattan distance was Euclidian distance squared (as in to save a sqrt) Thank you for saving my students a few points